# CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:4326: for geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, epsg

I am using anaconda for geopandas.
However, everytime I try to use epsg:4326:, it gives an error.

```
CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:4326: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name)
```

How can I solve this problem?

I tried:

```
from functools import partial
from pyproj import Proj, transform
proj_4326 = Proj(init="epsg:4326")
proj_3857 = Proj(init="epsg:3857")
```

I also tried to reset the environment:

```
conda update anaconda
```

but they both gave the same CRSError

My versions are:

```
import sys
import pyproj
import geopandas
```

```
print(sys.version)
print(pyproj.__version__)
print(geopandas.__version__)
```

```
3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ]
2.6.1.post1
0.8.2
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The code you show only uses pyproj. I cannot reproduce on a fresh install of pyproj over a Python 3.8 . What are your versions?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am using anaconda it says;ipython 7.19.0

Comment: @Lyliie I'm getting the same error while reading a geojson file. Please share with me if you found any solution to it?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. After a bit of a research I found out that anaconda will have a specific directory for geopandas and once it looks for pyproj there it won't find because in my case it was installed with pip as it was an ordeal to install geopandas in Windows(I usually work with Linux). The solution was remove geopandas with conda, then remove pyproj with pip. After it all is clean(try conda list to double check) I just use  conda install -c conda-forge geopandas and voilà!
I decided to share in case someone faces this annoyance. There is no point to look for the right format for your geodata.

Comment: This should be marked as the best solution. Thanks

Comment: thank you so much, I spent a long time trying to figure this one out...

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is as the following:

```
proj_4326 = Proj("epsg:4326")
proj_3857 = Proj("epsg:3857")
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, I finally had `crs=CRS("epsg:3857)` recognized by installing geopandas version 0.9.0 instead of the version installed by default (0.6.X both on Anaconda and pip from the OS).
I had also to assign a crs on a shapefile this way :

```
prov_shp=geopandas.read_file(fichier_dist )
prov_shp.set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)
```

...to be able to reproject from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 :

```
crs=CRS("epsg:3857")
prov_shp = prov_shp.to_crs(crs)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code give you basic projection, known as WGS84:

```
from pyproj import CRS

crs=CRS('EPSG:4326')
```

if you need proj4, do this:

```
from pyproj import CRS

crs=CRS('EPSG:4326').to_proj4()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1887

I've found this:

> Specifically in your case, it seems that you installed pyproj using pip (as a wheel, because it looks for PROJ data inside the pyproj package), and not with conda (although you are using a conda environment). It's best to install all those packages with conda (especially for non-pure python packages such as pyproj)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31583993)

Answer (score 0):

this is a version issue,
re-installed pyproj to 3.31 is able to solve problems

pip install pyproj==3.31 --user

Comment: This works. Not a specific version but latest seem to have solved the issue
`$pip install -U pyproj`

Answer (score 0):

Following ReinholdN's advice, I simply set the directory to the pyproj directory, as per [the documentation](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/datadir.html). In my case, it was in a different env, so anaconda3\envs\{env name}\Library\share\proj.

And I set it like this:

> pyproj.datadir.set_data_dir('directory')

> pyproj.datadir.get_data_dir() #check that it was set correctly

Answer (score -1):

conda create -n pyproj

conda activate pyproj

conda config --add channels conda-forge

conda config --set channel_priority strict

conda install pyproj

update: answer (y)

conda deactivate

conda env remove -n pyproj